# Where is this memory allocation allocated?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Here's the line of code:

```
A a = static_cast<A>(*(new A)); // ?
```

It compiles fine on 64bit clang at least.

But where is the memory actually allocated and what happens to variable a?

Comment: Don't do that. The memory is allocated by the call to `new`, but you lose access to the pointer, and you cannot ever `delete` it. Besides, if `A` was a builtin type, you'd also have undefined behaviour because of accessing a variable whose value is indeterminate.

Comment: To sum it all up -- C++ is *not* Java.  Code like this may work wonders in Java, but is an absolute no-no in C++ for the reasons given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question on the assumption that this line of code appears inside a function.  If it appears elsewhere, the bit about the "stack" is inaccurate but everything else is still accurate.

This line of code compiles to four operations, which we can write as their own lines of C++ to make things clearer.  It makes *two* allocations, in two different places, and one of them is "leaked".

```
A a;
{
    A *temp = new A;
    a = *temp;
}
```

The first operation allocates space for an object of type `A` on the "stack", and default-initializes it.  This object is accessible through the variable `a`.  It will be automatically destructed and deallocated no later than when the function returns; depending on surrounding context, this might happen earlier, but in no case while the variable `a` is in scope.

The second operation allocates space for *another* object of type `A`, but on the "heap" instead of the "stack".  This object is also default-initialized.  The `new` operator returns a pointer to this object, which the compiler stores in an temporary variable.  (I gave that variable the name `temp` because I had to give it *some* name; in your original code the temporary is not accessible by any means.)  This object will only ever be deallocated if, at some point in the future, the pointer returned by `new` is used in a `delete` operation.

The third operation, finally, copies the *contents* of the object on the heap, pointed to by `temp`, into the object on the stack, accessible via the variable `a`.  (Note: the `static_cast<A>(...)` that you had written here has no effect whatsoever, because `*temp` already has the type `A`.  Therefore, I took it out.)

Finally, the temporary variable holding the pointer to the object on the heap is discarded.  The object on the heap is ***not*** deallocated when this happens; in fact, it becomes impossible for anything ever to deallocate it.  That object is said to have *leaked*.

You probably wanted to write either

```
A a;
```

which allocates an object on the stack and does nothing else, or

```
// note: C++11 only; C++03 equivalent is std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
```

which allocates an object on the heap and arranges to reference-count it, so that it probably won't leak.  (There are a few other things you might have meant, but those are the most likely.)

Comment: About the last part and c++11, I think that `auto a = std::make_shared<A>();` would work.

Comment: @callmeSteve Thanks, that's exactly what I was failing to remember.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I tested this code but had no idea if it fails somehow I fail to notice.

Answer (score 4):

Besides there's no static cast needed, the memory allocated with `new A` simply leaks. You have lost access to that pointer and can never `delete` it properly anymore.

> But where is the memory actually allocated and what happens to variable a?

Variable `a` is destroyed as soon it leaves scope as usual.

Answer (score 2):

```
A a = static_cast<A>(*(new A)); // ?
```

This does the following.

```
(new A) // allocate a new A on the heap

*(new A) // the type is now A instead of *A

static_cast<A>(*(new A)) // makes it into an type A from type A in an potentially unsafe way (here it is a no-op as they are the same type)

A a = static_cast<A>(*(new A)); // copies the (default) value of A to a

; // leaks the allocted A as the last reference to it disappear.
```

Comment: _"makes it into an type A from type A in an unsafe way"_ What do you mean? The cast is just redundant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, should have said potentially unsafe way.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple definition of `A`, it is equivalent to:

```
A a(*new(A));
```

An `A` is dynamically allocated on the heap, `a` is copy constructed on the stack, and the dynamic allocation is leaked.

For a trivial definition of `A` the overall effect might as well be:

```
new A;
A a;
```

this copy implements the leak without the wasteful copy operation or the messy, redundant cast :)

Comment: Actually I tested this on my iMac compiled with clang and the memory was deallocated at the end of the method as expected.